# Do NPC's in Fallout 4 know how to use mines?

Tags: fallout-4

Will placing mines into settlers inventories allow them to use and place the mines?

Do they have unlimited uses like they have with grenades?

Comment: I've given them mines, a lot. But even after several fights, they usually have them in stock. But grenades, I think they use up.

Comment: I can confirm the same experience as @NVZ

Answer (score 2):

No. Settlers do not know how to use mines.

Comment: +1, but it's not just settlers.